# Beginners tutorial for Arduino Mega ADK

Tags: android, arduino, adk

Does anyone know of a good intro to controlling the Arduino Mega ADK with a handset? All I want to do is to control the LED on pin 13, using a very basic toggle switch app.

*Edit 26/10/11:*

http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/Index

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2011/05/17/understanding-the-demokit-pde-arduino-sketch/

https://github.com/deadfalkon/HelloADK

Now I'm stuck with the problem of getting My Galaxy S2 to connect in accessory mode...

*Edit 27/10/11*

http://sgccare.blogspot.com/2011/10/first-arduino-and-android-setup.html

Comment: I would like to let you know about http://electronics.stackexchange.com, a community more centered around hardware-related things! They may have a better answer for you.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, but there's very little ADK info on that site.

Answer (score 6):

Some of these links aren't yet the least code you need to blink an LED. I posted the exact solution to your question here: [Blink An LED With The ADK Board](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/).

Comment: does anyone know where this tutorial went?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the information at
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html
Usually it provides everything to get you up and running, complete with a sample application. If you can't connect, your are probably compiling against the wrong SDK version, but that is only a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the arduino site for more informations http://www.arduino.cc/. articles with [arduino tutorials](http://www.intorobotics.com/resources-and-tutorials-to-start-working-with-arduino-boards/) and how to could be found here:

http://arduino-for-beginners.blogspot.de/
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage
http://www.electroshopdendermonde.be/index.php/webshop/arduino-shop/arduino-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

here is an [Android Arduino Tutorial](http://www.softwaresupply.de/app-entwickler-blog/hardware-entwicklung-mit-android-und-arduino-das-tutorial), that describes all steps for controlling the ADK LED from the Android device. The tutorial is in German, but the code is helpful anyway.